# Transposition cipher - brute-force-attack - expected value

Tags: transposition-cipher

how do I calculate the expected value of a brute-force-attack on a transposition cipher? For example, for the text "HELLO", there are 5! = 120 possibilities. Is the expected value to break the transposition cipher with brute-force therefore 120? Or is it 120/2 = 60? Or something else?

Comment: If we are talking about the general transposition ciphers, it is a permutation.

Comment: Ok, i know what a permutation is, but how to calculate the expected value then?

Comment: Well, the number of permutations for placements is clear, however, you may not distinguish every possible permutation since Study and Dusty (anagrams) are in the same permutation.

Comment: Well, that's clear for me. But, I mean, if i try to break the cipher 1000 times with brute-force, then I will not always need 120 attemps to break the cipher. So basically my question is, how many attemps i will need on average (isn't that the definition of expected value?) and how to calculate this?

Comment: That really depends on the transposition. If the attack reveals the key, you need only once.

Comment: But how would a transposition reveal the key to an algorithm that just brute-forces the encrypted text? My example: A turning grille with 36 fields. So there are 30240 possibilities.

Comment: @chrysaetos99 brute force means you simply try keys until you get one right. Then, you have the key.